# "use self" in driver inside Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

I need to make a geonode that will be used by several objects.
I need to use a custom property inside the geonode.
This custom property is carried by the object that uses the geonode.

I thought that using the *Self Object* would let me access the properties of the object that uses the geonode. It doesn't.

[image]

Note that in my example, I do not try to access a custom property (yet), but just a simple scale ... No need to say that I get the same problem with a custom property ...

Am I doing something wrong?
Any idea?

Comment: Just try the node [Self Object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/self_object.html) in combination with [Object Info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/object_info.html) and [Separate XYZ](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/vector/separate_xyz.html). Then you have the *Location*.

Comment: You can't, probably for the same reason you can't do that inside a material. Some node trees can have multiple users. Geometry Node trees are evaluated separately for each object, so there is some room to implement it in Blender, but I'm 99% sure it is not yet implemented. What you can do is put a driver on the modifier, which is unique to each object. But then the driver won't be there when the modifier is added by some user of your asset… Of course if you relly want to access the location, then quellenform's suggestion will work.

Comment: Thanks you for your answers.

Alas, as I said, the location is not what I need. It is a custom property.
@Markus, I am 99% confident that you are 99% right when you say you're 99% sure.
And as there is a Self object node available, there is probably just a bit of work left to do to implement this.

Right now the object info node is relatively poor and does not provide much info.
A depressing workaround would be to pass a float value  through the scale of the object, for instance, and unscale the geometry within the Geonodes.
   
Should an improvement be proposed on Blender community ?